# Winforms: How to upload a picture into SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I want to upload images to my SQL Server database. I have two buttons , One picture box. With the browse button, I am able to select the file from disk, and it is displayed into the picturebox.

The problem is that I am not able to save the picture from picturebox into the database.

Please help me out with the code. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the image directly from its path (you have it already).

Try this:

```
    byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("your image path");

    mySqlCommand = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Image) VALUES(@Image)";//mySqlCommand is a SqlCommand, and @Image is a parameter 
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", img);
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sending/Receiving PictureBox Image in C# To/From Microsoft SQL SERVER](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PictureBoxImage.aspx)

Haven't tried the code myself.